# Kolmogorov-Smirnov Test in Python for Goodness of fit

Tags: python, scipy, statistics, statistical-test, kolmogorov-smirnov

I am trying to get the best distributions for my data.  The fitting is finished as shown in below figure, but i need a measurement, to choose the best model. I compared goodness of fit with a chi-squared value, and test for significant difference between observed and fitted distribution with a Kolmogorov-Smirnov (KS) test. I searched for some of potential solutions [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7903977/implementing-a-kolmogorov-smirnov-test-in-python-scipy),[2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51305126/kolmogorov-smirnov-test-for-the-fitting-goodness-in-python),[3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43093264/very-low-p-values-in-python-kolmogorov-smirnov-goodness-of-fit-test?rq=1) but I didn't get my answer.From the results in below figure:

1. If the `p-value` is higher than `k-statistic`, does it means we can accept the hypothesis or data fits the distribution well?
2. Alternatively, is it ok to compare `level of significance(a=0.005)` with `p-value` and decide the acceptance or rejection of hypothsis ? If `p-value` is lower than `a`, then it is very probable that the two distributions are different.
3. For `Kolmogorov-Smirnov test`, is it essential to standardised the data (-1,1) ?
4. Judging from the KS statistic and P-values, the `exponnorm` fits best in the data. Is that correct?

[image]

I calculated the P-value in following way:

```
for distribution in dist_names:
    # Set up distribution and get fitted distribution parameters
    dist = getattr(scipy.stats, distribution)
    param = dist.fit(y_std)   
    p = scipy.stats.kstest(y_std, distribution, args=param)[1]
    p = np.around(p, 5)
    p_values.append(p)
```

Answer (score 2):

1. No, you can either compare K-statistic to critical value in K-test critical value table or compare p-value to the level of significance, which is 0.005 in your case.
2. Right, in statistics, if p-value is small, we reject the null and accept the alternative one.
3. No, if we standardize the data before applying KS-test, we lose information about the distribution of raw data. For example, if data comes from a geometric distribution, after normalization, it is going to converge in distribution as normal (0,1) as the number of samples goes to infinity.
4. Yes, because p-value> a in this case, we fail to reject our null and accept this the input data has the same distribution as exponnorm. 
   By the way, this question should belong to [Cross Validated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/) since it is more or less related to statistical knowledge. Hope this answer helps you.

Comment: 1). For comparison between `K-statistic` to `critical value in K-test critical table`.If the `k-statistic value=0.0385` as shown in results figure, the K-test critical value table will be `D_crit=1.36/sqrt(n)=> 0.0057` ? where `n`= number of sample in data. Is that right? The `total samples=569`

Comment: @CaseMsee Exactly, since the sample size `n` is greater than 50, use `D_crit=1.36/sqrt(n)` instead of dividing the level of significance by n in the critical value table.

Comment: Thank you for great answer. Based on your feedback, I have some done analysis https://ibb.co/GnvT1x2. Can you please check?

Comment: In some of my datasets, I am getting `P_value=0` as shown https://ibb.co/XzN4qhK. I am not sure weather this is normal or not good as i am getting `K-static values`.